# Gazebo plugin's UpdateChild() not being called?

Tags: ros, nxt, gazebo-plugin, plugin, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm writing plugins for NXT and Gazebo and I was having trouble with the one I'm currently working...

After some time I realized that UpdateChild is never executed, or so I think. I have some *ROS_INFO("WTF");* calls that I use to follow the execution, and I can see the ones in LoadChild, InitChild and the callback node, but the one within UpdateChild is never shown.

This has not happened to me before, and I don't know what have I done differently...

BTW I'm using electric.

Here's the code for plugin that's not working, though you can also find it at my repository [here](https://bitbucket.org/Capelare/nxt_simulator/src/427978a79b6a27bfca9e616a99f04c5057eb8b3a/nxt_gazebo_plugins/src/nxt_light_plugin.cpp?at=master), along with the rest of my packages.

This plugin takes the data from a camera and calculates the luminance of the image.

The launch file I'm executing is [this one](https://bitbucket.org/Capelare/nxt_simulator/src/427978a79b6a/nxt_gazebo/launch/nxt_light_empty_world.launch?at=master).

Thanks in advance,
Miguel.

***Edit***: I'm removing the code here for the sake of readability.

Also, I tried reducing the plugin to its minimal expression (removing all functionality) and still seems to ignore UpdateChild function. WTF is happening? Any hints? :S

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47720/gazebo-plugin%27s-updatechild()-not-being-called?/) by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I may have solved it. I just simply added the following lines to the plugin call in the URDF description:

```
<alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
<updateRate>${update_rate}</updateRate>
```

I didn't know that was necessary! :'(

---

Originally posted by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) with karma: 202 on 2012-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0